# Rails nested resources and url helpers - how to shorten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources, url-helper

In my routes.rb file I have the following resources:

```
resources :educations do
  resources :semesters do
    resources :module_assignments do
      resources :module_exams do
        resources :module_marks
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which generates this url helper:

```
logonname_module_assignment_module_exams_path   GET /:student/module_assignments/:module_assignment_id/module_exams(.:format)   module_exams#index
```

Is there any way to shorten this? It should redirect to the same controller and the same action. Instead of

```
logonname_module_assignment_module_exams_path
```

I would prefer something like

```
module_exams_path
```

Is there a way to solve this? I want all url-helpers like this (index, new, edit, show etc.) not just the show path.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-as-in-nested-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to nest so deeply.

I personally only go as far as two deep, it just makes it easier to maintain.

But that doesn't answer the question. Or maybe it does.

With your setup. You could do something like:

`match '/:student/module_assignments/:module_assignment_id/module_exams(.:format)' => 'module_exams#index', :as => :module_exams`

This gives you `module_exams_path` as a helper.